# UIScrollView with multiple views(which is having button, scrollview and label)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app I am using a UIScrollView with multiple views (each view having buttons, scrollview and labels). By using for loop I am loading that views into UIScrollView. But when I tried to get touch actions in views inside UIScrollView only last view is able to access. How can we get touch access to all views inside UIScrollView?.

Any help or suggestion to do this.

Comment: show some code atleast to understand what you are doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign tag value to your all yourView then access your view

```
UIView *yourView = (UIView*)[ScrollView viewWithTag:tag];
```

Or

```
NSArray *yourView =(NSArray*)[ScrollView subviews];

NSLog(@"Your subView %@",[yourView objectAtIndex:index]);
```